# Removing Axis webservice in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I can't delete a deployed web service inside an Eclipse Dynamic Web Project.

I can't find the ws deployment anywhere in the Project Explorer window (i was looking for some icon to right click it and delete), so i tried this:

Removing the web service through Axis Administration Web page: the web service is removed from the list, but it's still there.

And If I delete the folder mydwpproject/services/servicename/, it spawns back the next time i reboot the Tomcat Server.

How am i supposed to get rid of the old web services?

Answer (score 0):

Going to the physical location of the project and deleting the .wsdl, related folder structure may help.